# How can I redirect the output of mingw64.exe to stdout?

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, io-redirection, msys2, mintty

I'm using `mingw-w64`, as provided by [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), to compile an application for Windows with a `Makefile`. As part of this process, I need to run a `configure` script within MSYS2. I can execute it in Windows like so:

```
PS C:\Users\Jesse\TheProject> mingw64 ./configure --arguments
```

<sup>(The particular application I'm working with uses `Makefile`s for its build system plus a custom `configure` Bash script to configure some variables. However, it's fully cross-platform.)</sup>

However, I don't have access to the `stdout` of this process; MSYS2 opens what I believe is a [`mintty`](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html) window, runs the command, and exits. I don't have any opportunity to parse the output, which I require for reasons beyond the scope of this post.

**My question is:** How can I make a command that's run via `mingw64` redirect its output to `stdout`, or at least to a file? If I can't literally use `mingw64.exe`, what can I do that's close enough?

Comment: `mingw64` is a rather high-level wrapper. I think `msys2_shell.cmd -mingw64 -c "command"` should work. Otherwise it's possible to directly call `C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe -c "command"`, but you might need to add a few env variables.

Comment: Why don't you go into the mingw64 interactive shell and the run `./configure` redirecting its output there like this `./configure --arguments > output.txt` ?

Comment: @BrechtSanders Interactivity isn't an option in my use case.